# How can I create a data.frame from a nested list with differing numbers of variable

Tags: r, list, nested-lists

I have downloaded a json file of Nobel Laureates and transformed it to a list, named 'nobels'. A couple of records are here shown in the structure

```
str(nobels)  

List of 1
$ laureates:List of 2
  ..$ :List of 13
  .. ..$ id             : chr "359"
  .. ..$ firstname      : chr "Axel Hugo Theodor"
  .. ..$ surname        : chr "Theorell"
  .. ..$ born           : chr "1903-07-06"
  .. ..$ died           : chr "1982-08-15"
  .. ..$ bornCountry    : chr "Sweden"
  .. ..$ bornCountryCode: chr "SE"
  .. ..$ bornCity       : chr "Linköping"
  .. ..$ diedCountry    : chr "Sweden"
  .. ..$ diedCountryCode: chr "SE"
  .. ..$ diedCity       : chr "Stockholm"
  .. ..$ gender         : chr "male"
  .. ..$ prizes         :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ :List of 5
  .. .. .. ..$ year        : chr "1955"
  .. .. .. ..$ category    : chr "medicine"
  .. .. .. ..$ share       : chr "1"
  .. .. .. ..$ motivation  : chr "\"for his discoveries concerning the nature and mode of action of oxidation enzymes\""
  .. .. .. ..$ affiliations:List of 1
  .. .. .. .. ..$ :List of 3
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ name   : chr "Karolinska Institutet, Nobel Medical Institute"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ city   : chr "Stockholm"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ country: chr "Sweden"

  ..$ :List of 10
  .. ..$ id             : chr "774"
  .. ..$ firstname      : chr "Richard"
  .. ..$ surname        : chr "Axel"
  .. ..$ born           : chr "1946-07-02"
  .. ..$ died           : chr "0000-00-00"
  .. ..$ bornCountry    : chr "USA"
  .. ..$ bornCountryCode: chr "US"
  .. ..$ bornCity       : chr "New York, NY"
  .. ..$ gender         : chr "male"
  .. ..$ prizes         :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ :List of 5
  .. .. .. ..$ year        : chr "2004"
  .. .. .. ..$ category    : chr "medicine"
  .. .. .. ..$ share       : chr "2"
  .. .. .. ..$ motivation  : chr "\"for their discoveries of odorant receptors and the organization of the olfactory system\""
  .. .. .. ..$ affiliations:List of 1
  .. .. .. .. ..$ :List of 3
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ name   : chr "Columbia University"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ city   : chr "New York, NY"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ country: chr "USA"
```

How should I go about transforming this into a data.frame?

Although there are lists within lists, I am happy to use, say, year and category and dispense with  prizes.

There is also the problem that not every record has the same number of variables - the second example here, for example, not providing the diedCountry field, amongst others

TIA

Profuse apologies. I should not really be doing this at night. The answers provided are fine for my original question. However, when I run the full list, I get an error

```
Error in data.frame(year = "1931", category = "literature", share = "1",  : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

Below is data causing this. It looks like it has something to do with the affiliations

```
nobels <- list(structure(list(id = "359", firstname = "Axel Hugo Theodor", 
surname = "Theorell", born = "1903-07-06", died = "1982-08-15", 
bornCountry = "Sweden", bornCountryCode = "SE", bornCity = "Linköping", 
diedCountry = "Sweden", diedCountryCode = "SE", diedCity = "Stockholm", 
gender = "male", prizes = list(structure(list(year = "1955", 
category = "medicine", share = "1", motivation = "\"for his discoveries concerning the          nature and mode of action of oxidation enzymes\"", 
affiliations = list(structure(list(name = "Karolinska Institutet, Nobel Medical    Institute", 
city = "Stockholm", country = "Sweden"), .Names = c("name", 
"city", "country")))), .Names = c("year", "category", 
"share", "motivation", "affiliations")))), .Names = c("id", 
"firstname", "surname", "born", "died", "bornCountry", "bornCountryCode", 
"bornCity", "diedCountry", "diedCountryCode", "diedCity", "gender", 
"prizes")), structure(list(id = "604", firstname = "Erik Axel", 
surname = "Karlfeldt", born = "1864-07-20", died = "1931-04-08", 
bornCountry = "Sweden", bornCountryCode = "SE", bornCity = "Karlbo", 
diedCountry = "Sweden", diedCountryCode = "SE", diedCity = "Stockholm", 
gender = "male", prizes = list(structure(list(year = "1931", 
category = "literature", share = "1", motivation = "\"The poetry of Erik Axel   Karlfeldt\"", 
affiliations = list(list())), .Names = c("year", "category", 
"share", "motivation", "affiliations")))), .Names = c("id", 
"firstname", "surname", "born", "died", "bornCountry", "bornCountryCode", 
"bornCity", "diedCountry", "diedCountryCode", "diedCity", "gender", 
"prizes")))
```

Comment: please add a `dput(head(your_list)`.

Comment: @pssguy It is better to show `dput` of your dataset (as I had shown in the post) to get an exact representation of the structure of your data.

Comment: @akrun. Sorry I had forgotten about dput. Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you identified correctly, the problem is occurring due to `affiliations`, whose sub-list is an empty list.

```
> str(nobels)
List of 2
 $ :List of 13
  ..$ id             : chr "359"
  ..$ firstname      : chr "Axel Hugo Theodor"
  ..$ surname        : chr "Theorell"
  ..$ born           : chr "1903-07-06"
  ..$ died           : chr "1982-08-15"
  ..$ bornCountry    : chr "Sweden"
  ..$ bornCountryCode: chr "SE"
  ..$ bornCity       : chr "Linköping"
  ..$ diedCountry    : chr "Sweden"
  ..$ diedCountryCode: chr "SE"
  ..$ diedCity       : chr "Stockholm"
  ..$ gender         : chr "male"
  ..$ prizes         :List of 1
  .. ..$ :List of 5
  .. .. ..$ year        : chr "1955"
  .. .. ..$ category    : chr "medicine"
  .. .. ..$ share       : chr "1"
  .. .. ..$ motivation  : chr "\"for his discoveries concerning the          nature and mode of action of oxidation enzymes\""
  .. .. ..$ affiliations:List of 1
  .. .. .. ..$ :List of 3
  .. .. .. .. ..$ name   : chr "Karolinska Institutet, Nobel Medical    Institute"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ city   : chr "Stockholm"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ country: chr "Sweden"
 $ :List of 13
  ..$ id             : chr "604"
  ..$ firstname      : chr "Erik Axel"
  ..$ surname        : chr "Karlfeldt"
  ..$ born           : chr "1864-07-20"
  ..$ died           : chr "1931-04-08"
  ..$ bornCountry    : chr "Sweden"
  ..$ bornCountryCode: chr "SE"
  ..$ bornCity       : chr "Karlbo"
  ..$ diedCountry    : chr "Sweden"
  ..$ diedCountryCode: chr "SE"
  ..$ diedCity       : chr "Stockholm"
  ..$ gender         : chr "male"
  ..$ prizes         :List of 1
  .. ..$ :List of 5
  .. .. ..$ year        : chr "1931"
  .. .. ..$ category    : chr "literature"
  .. .. ..$ share       : chr "1"
  .. .. ..$ motivation  : chr "\"The poetry of Erik Axel   Karlfeldt\""
  .. .. ..$ affiliations:List of 1
  .. .. .. ..$ : list()                             **<--problem here**
```

If you add some random data to that list, the code works fine.

```
nobels[[2]]$prizes[[1]]$affiliations[[1]]<-list(name="random data")
```

Use `plyr` package:

```
library (plyr)
mydf <- ldply(nobels, data.frame)
```

Comment: Thanks but I get the error Error in data.frame( 
  arguments imply differing number of rows - which is presumably because some of the list items do not include all the variables

Comment: @pssguy I tried this on the data shared by akrun in the other answer and didn't get any error.

Comment: @ujwal You are quite correct. The error I was getting was when running on full list. I think I have identified it in my edit above

Comment: @pssguy I have edited my answer above. can you try now?

Comment: Thanks. I ran through each element of list testing whether length(nobels[[i]]$prizes[[1]]$affiliations[[1]]) was zero and if so using your code. This created a new column (which I could subsequently dispense with) with a value of either 'random data' or NA. It also ensured that NA's got entered for those categories where the list was zero   Now just got to sort issue with multiple prizes for one laureate (e.g Marie Curie) and hopefully can actually analyse the data!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `unnest` from `tidyr`

```
 devtools::install_github("hadley/tidyr")
 library(tidyr)
```

Using your new dataset, this seems to work

```
  res1 <-unnest(lapply(nobels, function(x)
         as.data.frame.list(rapply(x,unlist), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)))

  str(res1)
  #Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  19 variables:
  #   $ id                         : chr  "359" "604"
  #$ firstname                  : chr  "Axel Hugo Theodor" "Erik Axel"
  #$ surname                    : chr  "Theorell" "Karlfeldt"
  #$ born                       : chr  "1903-07-06" "1864-07-20"
  #$ died                       : chr  "1982-08-15" "1931-04-08"
  #$ bornCountry                : chr  "Sweden" "Sweden"
  #$ bornCountryCode            : chr  "SE" "SE"
  #$ bornCity                   : chr  "Linköping" "Karlbo"
  #$ diedCountry                : chr  "Sweden" "Sweden"
  #$ diedCountryCode            : chr  "SE" "SE"
  #$ diedCity                   : chr  "Stockholm" "Stockholm"
  #$ gender                     : chr  "male" "male"
  #$ prizes.year                : chr  "1955" "1931"
  #$ prizes.category            : chr  "medicine" "literature"
  #$ prizes.share               : chr  "1" "1"
  #$ prizes.motivation          : chr  "\"for his discoveries concerning the          nature and mode of action of oxidation enzymes\"" "\"The poetry of Erik Axel   Karlfeldt\""
  #$ prizes.affiliations.name   : chr  "Karolinska Institutet, Nobel Medical    Institute" NA
 #$ prizes.affiliations.city   : chr  "Stockholm" NA
 #$ prizes.affiliations.country: chr  "Sweden" NA
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to remedy ny shortcomings and introducing me to unnest in the tidyr package. As you will see from above I still have issues with some of my data which I have reproduced above